# Scale specific row values in SQL, based on the sums of colums in the same group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hope somebody can help me this because I am having trouble finding solution to this

I have the following data for produced units in a manufacturing line:

[image]

For a specific shift I need to have:

`SUM(Total Count Yield) - SUM(Good Count Yield) = SUM(Defect Count Yield)`

So what I was thinking is scaling the defects up or down by a ratio that would satisfy the above formula. NB. If the result is out by 1-2% it is still acceptable.

To find what all the defects should add up to in a shift

> D-actual = (SUM of all Good Count Yield values for a shift)
>    - (SUM of all Total Yield values for a shift)

To find the current defects

> D-current = (SUM of all Defect Count Yield values for a shift)

So the ratio to scale all the defect counts for a specific shift is:

> r = D-actual/D-current.

Can somebody point me in the right direction to write this in to a SQL query?

EDIT:

So for Shift 1 in the previous data the defect count should be:

> Total_SUM(100 + 100 + 300) - Good_SUM(100 + 150 + 100) = 150

But in actual fact the default count is:

> Defect_SUM(220 + 240 + 200) = 660

So I want to scale all my defects in shift 1 by a factor of r = 150/660. For example:

> Row ID 3 will have a Yield of 220 * (150/660) = 50
>   Row ID 6 will have a Yield of 240 * (150/660) = 54
>   Row ID 9 will have a Yield of 200 * (150/660) = 45

The total defect count for that shift will then be 50 + 54 + 45 = 149 which is within my error margin.

Comment: Table definitions, some sample data, wanted result please. And also your current SQL statement, and describe whats wrong with it.

Comment: I don't have a statement. My SQL skills are limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If am not wrong you need to use `Conditional Aggregate`. Try this.

```
SELECT shift,
       D_actual = Sum(CASE WHEN name = 'Good Count' THEN yeild ELSE 0 END) 
                    - Sum(CASE WHEN name = 'Total Count' THEN yeild ELSE 0 END) ,
       D_Current = Sum(CASE WHEN name = 'Defect Count' THEN yeild ELSE 0 END),
       R = ( Sum(CASE WHEN name = 'Good Count' THEN yeild ELSE 0 END) 
               - Sum(CASE WHEN name = 'Total Count' THEN yeild ELSE 0 END) ) 
                      / Sum(CASE WHEN name = 'Defect Count' THEN yeild ELSE 0 END) 
FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY shift
```

or do the grouping in `CTE` or `sub-select` which is more readable

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT shift,
                D_actual= Sum(CASE WHEN name = 'Good Count' THEN yeild ELSE 0 END) 
                          - Sum(CASE WHEN name = 'Total Count' THEN yeild ELSE 0 END),
                D_Current= Sum(CASE WHEN name = 'Defect Count' THEN yeild ELSE 0 END)
         FROM   yourtable
         GROUP  BY shift)
SELECT shift,
       D_actual,
       D_Current,
       r=D_actual / D_Current
FROM   cte
```

Comment: Thanks. So I should just use an update with this nested inside of it?

Comment: @user18593 - not sure what you are talking about. Which column you want to update

Comment: Well each defect must be multiplied by the R value for its shift. So for shift 1 I will need to multiply the three defects by 150/660 each. I'm thinking of joining the result from your select on to the main table (so that the R value is in the same row as the defect, then updating the value)

Comment: Thanks a lot NoDisplayName. I got it working thanks to your first code block. I simply joined the results from your code to the original table, then I updated the table's Yield with itself times the joined R.